# See the differences between 2 projects

Tags: c#, xamarin, tfs

I recently had to code on a Mac for an application that requiered Xamarin IOS.
I now have to add the code I created on the mac to my tfs. 
However to do this I have to see every thing I added since then. Is there like a windows command or a software to see all the differences between 2 projects? 
I hope my question was clear 
Best Regards

Edit: I just love the downvotes for asking a question such a nice helpful community at least comment and explain why you are downvoting

Comment: Are you using source control? I assume you mean these are the same project just different versions?

Comment: Yes that's it the problem is with tfs I cannot just replace the folder containing the solution I need to change each file where modifications were made individually.

Comment: you're getting downvotes because you're asking us to find you a tool which is off topic for so. You would know that if you read through [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they both are on .NET framework then you have a `*.csproj` file. You can then use the `FC` File Compare command to see the differences like

```
FC mac.csproj win.csproj
```

To know more about the command check `FC /?` in command prompt

Comment: We don´t want questions about software/tools or docs on SO, do we? They attract dozens of similar (possibly opinated) answers.

Comment: Hello I need to compare all my files in the solution not only the csproj sorry if it wasn"t clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that:

1. In VS, select each file of the first project in source control explorer, right-click --> Compare --> then select the file in another projects to compare.
2. Copy/Download the two projects to local folder. Install compare tool
   such as [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_multifaceted), [ExamDiff Pro](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp), they can compare directories and binary files.

   - [Working with ExamDiff Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8-YserQN3U)
   - [Introduction to Beyond Compare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGAyWvstKCI)